# KnownFolders with different frameworks

Tags: c#, windows, special-folders, known-folders

I'm searching for a way to retrieve [KnownFolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with framework 2.0, 3.5 or 4.0 (mainly 2.0)

Is there a C# method for the Windows API function [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

If found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx), but it is only for Windows 8 store apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [System.Environment.GetFolderPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) (available since .NET 1.0).

It takes one of the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enum values as a parameter.